# How can i call the method from one controller in another controller in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have been searching the net for last few hours but cannot find how to call one of method in a controller that I have created in another controller which will be used then to populate my html page in my view.

The method I am trying to call  is this one:

```
class CataloguesController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @catalogues = Catalogue.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @catalogues }
    end
```

and i am trying to call it in the following method:

```
      def index
    session[:cart].catalogues = Catalogue.all
  end
```

Rails in not having and is returning the following error when i run it in my html page.

```
undefined method `catalogues=' for {:id=>5}:Hash
```

Any help will be much appreciated...

**EDIT**

cart_controller

```
class CartController < ApplicationController

  before_filter do
    session[:cart] = session[:cart] || {} # set an empty cart if no cart exist
  end



  def index
    session[:cart].catalogues = Catalogue.all
  end

  def success
  end


  def add
    id = params[:id]
    amount = session[:cart][id] || 0 # gets cart amount or 0 if no amount was found
    session[:cart][id] = amount + 1 # set new amount
    @catalogue = Catalogue.find(params[:id])
    session[:cart]  = {:id => @catalogue.id }
    redirect_to action: "index"

    # @catalogue = Catalogue.find(params[:id])
    # session[:cart] = cart
    # cart = {:id => @catalogue.id, :catalogue => @catalogue.name,category => @catalogue.category, :code => @catalogue.code , :colour=> @catalogue.colour, :description => @catalogue.description, :image  => @catalogue.image , :unitprice => @catalogue.unitprice, :unitquantity => @catalogue.unitquantity, :unitweight => @catalogue.unitweight }
    # session[:cart] = cart
    # render 'cart/add'
  end

  def remove 

  end

  def clear
  end

  def checkout

  end

end
```

Comment: what is session[:cart] describing? Is it an object? Is it just a hash? What is it? Where is it defined? Apparently, session[:cart]={:id=>5}... This does not mean anything...

Comment: I have a catalogue model/controller and it s own view... and i have created a cart controller, the cart will save the id of the catalogue in a session then i will let rails find the all those id's saved and match them then display the catalogue based on those id.

Comment: I will put up my code for the cart_controller

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, so I just reply to the question in the title. Have you read the rails guide? If you did and you could not found anything about how to call another controller's method from controller, you should ask the question yourself, why is that? I can tell you, because you should not do anything like that.

Comment: Then how do i call the content from the catalogue model in my cart controller?

Comment: Try this: Cart.find(session[:cart][:id]).catalogues = Catalogue.all

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What's the goal ?

Comment: Double on Rails Fan's comment. Do yourself a great favor and read the tutorial

Comment: @KirtiThorat. Not working with your code, returns error 
uninitialized constant CartController::Cart